# Pass dynamically an array of product IDs to Woocommerce "products" shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I am using a theme and have a custom post type 'Seller'. I have products in WooCommerce where a product is assigned a seller through Advanced Custom fields. Within my single-seller.php I have:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[products]'); ?>
```

Which returns the products perfectly as the theme is intended. I have a query which I could foreach through and display my own code:

```
$relatedProducts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'seller', //ACF field name
            'value' => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
    'numposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
));
```

Could I pass the shortcode an ids argument and what would be the best way to do this?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[products ids=""]'); ?>
```

Cheers all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already [an **`ids`** argument](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcode_Products.html#119) for woocommerce `[products]` shortcode that you can use…

In the `get_posts()` funtion you will add the the arguments array:

```
'fields'     => 'ids',
```

to get an array of products IDs…

Then using `implode()` function to convert your products ids array to a string of ids, you will be able to include the ids as a string in your shortcode, this way:

```
<?php // Your query
$related_ids = get_posts(array(
    'meta_query'  => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'seller', //ACF field name
            'value'   => get_the_ID(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
    'numposts'    => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'fields'      => 'ids', // <==== HERE to get an array of IDs
)); ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode("[products ids='".implode(',',$related_ids)."']"); ?>
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Awesome answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Is your own shortcode? Here is how to create shortcode with arguments: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/

And in query you will have to add

```
'post__in' => array(<put list of id here, separated by comma>)
```